# Why my WPF binding not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, objectdataprovider

I trying to bind List to Listbox. And at the Button1Click method new instance of MyClass adds in my List<>, but that not visible in my listbox. There my code:

```
       public static class NotesEngine
            {
                public static List<Note> All;

                static NotesEngine()
                {
                    All = new List<Note>
                              {
                                  new Note
                                      {
                                          Content = "test1",
                                      }
                              };
                }

                public static List<Note> GetNotes()
                {
                    return All;
                }
}
```

It is my form episode and ObjectDataProvider:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type NotesEngine}" x:Key="NotesList" MethodName="GetNotes"/>

......

<TabItem Header="test" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource NotesList}}">

                <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NotesListBoxDataTemplate}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding }">
                </ListBox>
</TabItem>

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NotesEngine.All.Add(new Note
                            {
                                Content = "xx",
                                Images = new List<string>(),
                                LastEdit = DateTime.Now,
                                Title = "XASAC",
                            });
}
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ObservableCollection<Node>` instead of `List<Node>`. **ObservableCollection** is a generic dynamic data collection that provides notifications (using an interface "`INotifyCollectionChanged`") when items get added, removed, or when the whole collection is refreshed. List does not implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which interface is used by WPF ListBox to update UI.

see

1. [ObservableCollection<(Of <(T>)>) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)
2. [An Introduction to ObservableCollection in WPF](http://sweux.com/blogs/psampaio/index.php/2009/04/28/an-introduction-to-observablecollection-in-wpf/)
3. [List vs ObservableCollection vs INotifyPropertyChanged in Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx)